# Elastic collisions and internal degrees of freedom

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision, degrees-of-freedom

As I was considering elastic collisions today a question popped into my head. Do elastic collisions imply that there are no internal degrees of freedom in the colliding objects which couple effectively to the degrees of freedom associated with the collision?

I can imagine there are situations where an elastic collision does involve internal degrees of freedom that are excited but then due to the specific initial conditions those internal degrees of freedom can transfer energy back into the degrees of freedom associated with the relative motion of the colliding objects. But if I have a system in which, no matter the initial conditions, when two objects collide the collision is elastic, does this provide evidence that there are no internal degrees of freedom in the colliding objects? Or at least that those internal degrees of freedom don't couple with the degrees of freedom associated with the relative motion of the colliding objects?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a mass with an ideal spring attached to it colliding with a wall and bouncing back: the compression of the spring is the internal degree of freedom, but the collision is elastic. Similar thing, but with a lot more degrees of freedom, happens when a ball is reflected by a wall or floor.

What makes a collision inelastic is that the mechanical energy of the objects (considered as material points/center-of-mass) in the initial state and the final state is not the same (i.e., part of it is converted to other kinds of energy *and is not recovered*.)

Comment: If you treat your example mass with a spring as a point mass, then there are all sorts of collisions that won't be elastic. If the mass strikes the wall so that the spring is off center, some of the translational kinetic energy becomes rotational kinetic energy, which is essentially "lost" if treating the mass and spring as a point mass. I'm not arguing that elastic collisions can't occur with the presence of internal degrees of freedom. The question is whether an inability to find any initial conditions that lead to inelastic behavior implies a lack of accessible internal degrees of freedom.

Comment: @scmartin you have a point here: I assumed 1d motion in this example... but you essentially add more degrees of freedom for spring. Consider a ball instead - it fan bounce at an angle elastically.

Comment: Let's assume the ball has internal degrees of freedom described by the phonon modes of the ball. If one of the phonon modes is in a high amplitude excitation before the collision with the wall, the ball could potentially transfer energy out of the phonon mode and into its translational motion. How much transfers between the excited phonon and the translational motion would, I presume, depend on during which part of the phonon modes period motion the collision occurred.

Comment: @scmartin this could happen, and does happen - e.g., in Raman scattering.

Comment: And in the case of Raman scattering, this indicates an internal degree of freedom (the vibrational state of the molecule) that can couple with the degrees of freedom associated with the collision (though I'm not sure how to think about the degrees of freedom of a photon; certainly its momentum changes though). My point is that the inelastic nature of the collision indicates there must be internal degrees of freedom in the things that are colliding. What I'm wondering is whether the converse is true: that not being able to force elastic scattering indicates no internal available DOF.